# php how to pass parameters in function?

Tags: php

I have a function:

```
function passParams($a, $b = null, $c)
{
    echo "<pre>"; var_dump($a); echo "<br/>"; die('123');
}
```

and I want to call it like this:

```
passParams($a = 10, $c = 1);
```

How do I have to?

Answer (score 2):

Try this...

```
<?php
function addFunction($num1, $num2,$test=NULL)
{
  $sum = $num1 + $num2;
  echo "Sum of the two numbers is : $sum";
}
addFunction(10, 20,NULL);
?>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php

Comment: yes. I know that, but now I want to call the function with 2 params, the rest of param will be set default value when it isn't passed

Answer (score 1):

Define parameters with default values at the end of function arguments.

```
function passParams($a, $c, $b = null)
{
    echo "<pre>"; var_dump($a); echo "<br/>"; die('123');
}
```

And call it by -

```
passParams(10, 1);
```

Then -

```
$a will be - 10
$b will be - NULL
$c will be - 1
```

Comment: Thanks. so we have to call by order of parameters?

Comment: Yup. The order will set them accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can always call like this:

```
passParams(10, NULL, 1);
```

This way 2nd parameter will remain its default value as specified in the function

Comment: *I want to call the function with 2 params, the rest of param will be set default value when it isn't passed*